# Shift HashiCorp Vault secrets from one path (sub dir) to another

Tags: vault

Good morning !

I am using Vault from HashiCorp and would like to move secrets and secrets structure around.

I have a bunch of secrets under a path, let say:

- boo/foo/
- boo/foo/bar/secret1
- boo/foo/bar/secret2
- boo/foo/bar/secret3
- boo/foo/bar/secretn+

But I need to move all of theses secrets, or even all of foo/ under another path on my Hashi Vault.

Is there any function from the Vault API to achieve that or Ill need to wrap the API with a script to achieve that ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no recursive (-r) function either with the API or the VAULT client. (It is documented)

So if you need to do change in ''batch'', I suggest you write a for loop that will do it for you by copying the data from one path to another, then deleting the secrets from the old path.

This is the only way.